# Changing polygon boundary thickness/color

Tags: qgis, symbology

[image]How can I make the polygon boundaries of admin 1 thicker than thous admin 2? I. e. I want to make the province boundaries thicker than its district boundaries.

Comment: Just double-click a "square" for a label which will bring you to another set of options. Here you can define size, colour etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can just change the details of the symbols by double clicking the box where the symbol is defined. 
[image]

That will open up a new window which will allow you to change the borders, the color, thickness, etc.
[image]

You can do this for all the symbols that you want to change.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be:

1. Define a rule based style on the layer
2. Add one rule for all features that do not equal "admin 1" make the symbol boarder thin
3. Add another rule for all features that do equal "admin 1" make the symbol boarder thicker

Comment: Thank you artwork21. But I am already defining a graduated style rule. If I added a rule based style, will this keep my graduated style rule?